# Обучить нейросеть говорить голосом персонажа

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Недавно у меня появилась идея для одного проекта и я хочу обучить говорить нейросеть голосом персонажей, "скормив" ей их разговори. Я абсолютный новичок в этой сфере, поэтому не знаю, возможно ли подобное провернуть? Если да - то что нужно использовать и какие сложности могут возникнуть в процессе?

Буду очень рад Вашей консультации.

Comment: А говорить то что она должна, текст какой-то? Начните с изучения темы `text2speech` или `TTS`.

Comment: @CrazyElf да, она будет говорить текст, сгенерированный Бардом. Спасибо за совет!